# How to handle two unrelated events with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm wondering if I can fire off both of these events together :

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").click(function(){
   if($(this).is(":checked"))
   {
       //Value of checkbox
       alert(this.value);
   }
});
```

and

```
$("input[type= 'text']").keyup(function(){
   alert(this.value);
});
```

I looked into .bind, but that seems to only work for one selected elements (i.e. `$(p).bind("mouseout mouseenter).doSomething())`.

The situation I am running into is that I have a function that needs to fire anytime either one of these things occur.

Comment: No, there really isn't. You've got two different selectors (A, B) and two different events (X, Y), you can't bind A.X and B.Y in one statement without also binding A.Y and B.X.

Comment: You're terminology is also backwards; you're trying to *bind* events, not *fire* events. Talking about "firing off" two events doesn't make sense given the code you're posting, which involves *binding* to two events.

Comment: @meagar I guess I could just scan the entire pages checkboxes and text fields for their values in either event, since that is what I need anyways.

Comment: Err, if that's your intent you might want to see my answer first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ways you can achieve this as shown below:

1. using "on" method:

   ```
   $(document).on('keyup click',"input[type=checkbox],input[type='text']", function(){
      // Do stuff here..
   })
   ```
2. Call function after the event.

   ```
   $("input[type=checkbox]").click(doSomething);
   $("input[type= 'text']").keyup(doSomething);

   function doSomething() {

   }
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$("input[type=checkbox],input[type='text']").on('click keyup', function(){
   // code
});
```

Comment: Note that this isn't equivalent: You're also binding `input[type=checkbox] keyup` and `input[type='text'] click`, two events which *will* occur quite frequently in the course of using a form.

Answer (score 0):

If you still need the additional if, you can use:

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").click(function(){
   if($(this).is(":checked"))
   {
       //Value of checkbox
       alert(this.value);
       somethingHappened();
   }
});

$("input[type= 'text']").keyup(function(){
   alert(this.value);
   somethingHappened();
});

function somethingHappened() {
   // Do stuff
}
```

Comment: I am thinking of doing something along these lines. Thanks for your input, I was looking at going about it the wrong way. This is easier.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps all you need is a common function?

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").click(function(){
   if($(this).is(":checked")) {
       special(this.value);
   }
});

$("input[type= 'text']").keyup(function(){
   special(this.value);
});

function special(val) {
   alert(val);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your intent really is to invoke a function when any checkboxes/text fields across the whole page changes, you probably want something like this:

```
$('body').on('change', ':checkbox,:text', function () {


});
```

Note that the `:checkbox` and `:text` selectors are much nicer than `input[type=checkbox]` etc.

Comment: `:checkbox` and `:text` selectors are deprecated.